# Lista de seleccion en formulario

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

estoy intentando de poner a la hora de crear un formulario un listado de categorías que debe seleccionar el cliente, pero estoy teniendo problemas ya que no me trae el array que quiero y me dice que la variable esta indefinida os dejo el código para ver donde estoy fallando, gracias.

```php
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //

        $query = Categoria::pluck('titulo', 'id')->toArray();

        dd($query);

        return view('portfolio.crear', compact('query'));


    }
```

```php
            {{ Form::open(['route' => 'portfolio.store' , 'method' => 'post' , 'files' => true]) }}
            <div class="box-body">
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        {{ Form::label('category_id', 'Categoria') }}
                        {{ Form::select('category_id', $query, null,  array("class" =>"form-control")) }}
                        @if ($errors->has('category_id'))
                            <small class="form-text text-danger">{{ $errors->first('category_id') }} </small>
                        @endif
                    </div>
```

Comment: muestra la ruta que lleva a ese método del controlador y agrega el nombre de la vista donde está ese formulario. si en el controlador tienes un método create, también agregalo a la pregunta con su respectiva ruta

Answer (score 0):

Podrías mostrar el mensaje de error por favor?
Prueba en añadir tu variable de esta manera en tu controlador:

```
return view('portfolio.crear')->with(compact('query'));
```